# How do I make changes to module-level objects stick in Python? (like Pylons meta objects)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm working on a Python server application using SQLAlchemy for database access. I would like to have engine, session and metadata objects in a meta.py module that are used throughout the program to access the database (like the Pylons convention).

The engine and session objects are initialized as `None` in the meta.py module, and then actually assigned real values in other modules. E.g.

`model/meta.py`:

```
engine = None
Session = None
metadata = Metadata()
```

`model/__init__.py`:

```
from simplesite.model import meta

def init_model():
    # ...
    sm = orm.sessionmaker(...)
    meta.Session = orm.scoped_session(sm)
```

The trouble is when I import and run `init_model()` in another module, then import Session from meta.py, it is still set to None. I.e.

```
from model.meta import Session
from model import init_model

init_model()
# Session is still None!
```

Could someone please tell me why this is and/or how how it works in Pylons applications? I'm guessing the answer would be something more fundamental about how Python works?

Alternative suggestions on how to have a single point of database access throughout an application would also be appreciated (i.e. best practices for using SQLAlchemy in large applications).

Comment: What you're doing is fine. The problem is that `from model.meta import Session` binds the value in `meta.Session` to the name `Session`, which doesn't change when the name `meta.Session` changes. Instead, just do `from model import meta` and then look up `Session` as `meta.Session`.

Comment: In fact, think how unpleasant it would be if code from another module could _change your local variables_!!

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. I'm now using from model import meta, then referring to the object by meta.Session and it works

Comment: Please answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this since it looks like it's just sitting here, although an answer was given in the comments by @katrielalex.

When you do `from model.meta import Session`, you create a new local variable called `Session` that is bound to the object from that module.  When `init_model()` runs, it rebinds the name inside the `meta` module, but this doesn't affect your local variable.

You can achieve your desired effect by not accessing `meta.Session` until after `init_model()` has done its work:

```
from model import meta
from model import init_model
init_model()
Session = meta.Session
```